# How to insert a table into another table's entry in SQL

Tags: postgresql

Let's suppose I have a table:

```
name   amt
A       1    
B       3    
C       8
```

And I now want to insert that table into another table's entry. For the purpose of this example lets say we insert that table into entry X:

```
name       table
Z    
X          A 1, B 3, C 8    
Y
```

What query can I use to do this?

The values can be comma separated, in fact I am not too worried about the format, I just need that data in the entry.

Underlying problem (Why I want to do this):
Let's say I have a group of districts. Lets call them districts A, B, and C. Now I would like to know the number of red, blue, and green houses in district A. Simple, I just make a new table that would filter out districts B and C and then count the groups of houses. So, assuming I have 8 red houses, 12 blue houses, and 2 green houses, we get the resulting table:

```
# of houses      color
12               blue
8                red 
2                green
```

I now want to store this in our original table for future reference. So I make a new column, and add

```
District       Group_Data
A              12 blue, 8 red, 2 green
B
C
```

Now in the future I may want to do the same for districts B and C, and the same process would follow.

Any other ways to solve this problem are welcome if simpler.

Comment: This can be done, but why in the world would you want to insert an entire table of data into a single row in another table?

Comment: It's a long story haha

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  You should also explain why you want to do this, because it seems rather unusual.

Comment: I edited the tag thanks. The reason is a little difficult to explain, and therefore I'll refrain from writing it all out.

Comment: @segfault Explain the underlying problem. Any answer to this question is bound to make you unhappy. It is better to find a good solution for your real problem.

Comment: Ok, I added a motivation

Comment: Well ok that is just bad design. Don't normalize your database, denormalize them using join tables and reference tables.

Comment: @WilomGfx can you expand on this in an answer? I am still a bit new to SQL so this would really help, thanks!

Comment: @WilomGfx: You got that backwards.  Don't *de-normalize*, keep it normalized.  (That is, keep it relational and queryable instead of trying to flatten all the data.)